# Custom background style for Tab button (Sherlock type)

Tags: android, tabs, styles, actionbarsherlock

I would like create custom backgound style for Sherlock Tab button in ViewPager. I'm using selector in xml with states. Everything work but setting style for background in selected states not work. So, how can I set custom background style for Tab button (Sherlock type) if Tab button is selected?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried googling it?

Comment: I tried everything possible, Googling for 4 hours ... nothing.